# Responding with JSON, XML, or Other, based on .{Type} using web.py

Tags: python, url, rest, web.py

I am trying to set response type based on the .{Type} at the end of a URL for a RESTful API using web.py.

How can I pass .JSON, .XML, .HTML, .(whatever) to the class "Assignments" or set it as a value somewhere so that ServerResponse can receive it and respond with the proper format?

I tried:

```
'/assignments(\.[:upper:]+)', 'Assignments'
```

I'm using the following code for my urls:

```
urls = (
    '/(.*)/', 'redirect',
    '/', 'Homepage',
    '/assignments', 'Assignments'
)
```

I have a class "Assignments":

```
class Assignments:
    def GET(self,responseType):
        sentData = web.data()
        query = JSON.decode(sentData,'unicode')
        # \/ Replace With Code \/
        data = query 
        # /\ Replace with Code /\
        return ServerResponse.Send(data,responseType)

    def POST(self,responseType):
        sentData = web.data()
        query = JSON.decode(sentData,'unicode')
        # \/ Replace With Code \/
        data = query 
        # /\ Replace with Code /\
        return ServerResponse.Send(data,responseType)
```

And my ServerResponse class:

```
class ServerResponse:
    @staticmethod
    def Send(data, method):
        return getattr(ServerResponse, method)(data)

    @staticmethod
    def JSON(data):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        response = JSON.encode(data)
        return response

    @staticmethod
    def XML(data):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def HTML(data):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        response  = "<html>"
        response += "<head></head>"
        response += "<body>"
        response += "{"
        for key in data:
            response += "%s:%s,\n" % (str(key), str(data[key]))
        response += "}"
        response += "</body>"
        response += "</html>"
        return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to implement simple restful controller for web.py and currently using its derivative in one project to communicate with backbone.js, you may check it here: https://gist.github.com/3907294

Also, there is https://github.com/martinblech/mimerender you may find useful, but it rather checks http accept header to determine render format.

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly, then the code I need to look at is:
resources(?:/(?P<resource_id>[0-9]+))?(?:\.(?P<format>[a-z]+))?',

Specifically the ?(?:\.(?P<format>[a-z]+))? portion... this appears to take anything after a . and send it to the variable format?

Is that correct?

Comment: It appears that this string dd exactly what I needed: (?:\.(?P<dataFormat>[A-Z]+))?

Thank you!

Comment: Yep, web.py applies regex to url and capture groups are sent to the controller arguments